# форматирование кода IntelijIdea

Tags: intellij-idea, code-style

Доброго времени суток всем.
Хотел узнать, если кто знает, возможно ли задать порядок и позицию автоматического выравнивания полей в IntelijIdea? Я к примеру хочу, чтобы поля класса шли следующим образом:

- static final
- empty line
- static
- empty line
- final
- empty line
- other

Если кто-то может, подскажите пожалуйста, потому что я пока не нашел как это сделать. Не исключено что ищу как-то не так или не то, так что извиняюсь заранее.

Comment: Форматирование кода можно вызвать с помощью: Code -> Reformat Code. Или же комбинацией Ctrl+Alt+L

Comment: Спасибо. Я знаю как отформатировать код. Я хотел узнать каким образом можно настроить определенный паттерн для задания четко определенного порядка следования полей с разделением пустыми строками. Какие опции нужно задать для этого.

Answer (score 0):

То есть изменения стиля кола. Я знаю, что это модно сделать в File\Setting...\Edit\Code Style\<нужный язык>, но я никогда не углублялся в это, так что дальше я вам ничем не помогу. Более подробная информацию читайте здесь [JetBrainds Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html)